# How to avoid millions of simple products when using configurable product for t-shirts

Tags: configurable-product

I have a problem.  I have 1000 T-Shirts that each have 7 size options, 10 colour options and 7 print options.  I create a configurable product and then add each simple associated product for each option.

Lucky I have an extension that creates all the associated simple products for each of my configurable products.

However, this adds up to 700 simple products for each of my 1000 T-Shirts.  or 7 million unique simple products.  Which I think you will agree is a lot. OK each of the simple products is not visible on the front end but nevertheless, that is a lot of DB records.

I know that I can use custom options for this task as I dont need to manage stock as each T-Shirt is custom made. However, I am using M2ePro to sysc my product cat with **ebay** and this appears to need configurable products in order to create product variations

Any ideas would be great
Thanks

Comment: Do you need to track inventory?

Comment: Actually that doesn't matter so much, you can get extensions that add inventory to custom options or you just do the 'better to ask forgiveness than ask permission' approach if you have most or all available and only have the odd inventory problem.

Comment: I do not need to track inventory, no

Answer (score 2):

Possible solution is a custom options extension that store the same options in one place, so you don't need to multiply them for each individual product. Or a new product type.  But both solutions require advanced development.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use M2E then you have to create real products/skus to be able to list them on ebay. But probably you are right that having 7m skus is not the best idea. At least syncing 7m skus to Ebay is a rather time consuming process.